# Run impacted tests right after code change

Tags: automated-testing, tools, unit-tests

I have partial memory recollection of product for .NET and Visual Studio that runs impacted unit tests right after you change one line or something like that. It has some smart code impact detection and test scheduler. Does anyone know anything about such product? I've forgotten even how to google for it.

Comment: It sound's very interesting. I was wondering how beneficial would be use such a tool. 
I've found this searching for the keywords you mentioned: [Parasoft Stuff](http://www.parasoft.com/solutions/dotnet_solution.jsp).

Comment: One option is going the "Continuous Integration" way. You can have your tests executed as soon as a build is created. But it's not selective, as you mentioned is what you are looking for.

Comment: @SayusiAndo Thx. It's close. I remembered I've seen screencast on the main page showcasing near real time test execution and red or green icons on each line showing pass or fail test results.

Comment: @Yash "Continuous Integration" is not the answer I was looking for. Thank you for trying to help. Guess question is not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that Google keywords for finding the product I was looking for.net were

*parallel test runner*

which, with my .NET affiliation that Google knows about, led me to article on [Smart Continuous Test-Runner For .NET – For Free](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/06/continuous-test-runner-net). **[NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/)** was the one I was looking for, but found out about AutoTest.NET and Mighty Moose which are nice alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Hard part is to figure out which tests to run for change of certain source file.

Nose-knows builds this relationships from coverage analysis: [Announcement](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.testing.general/5873) - for Python.

It is on my list to try in my copious free time.

Comment: Yeah. Something like that but for .NET.